# How to copy a surface mesh in CGAL

Tags: mesh, cgal

I want to copy a mesh with the function `copy_face_graph(source, target)`. But the target mesh is different (it has same number of vertices and faces, but the coordinates and the order are totally different).

The code:

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <CGAL/boost/graph/copy_face_graph.h>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel   Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<Kernel::Point_3>                   Mesh;
namespace PMP = CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const char* filename1 = (argc > 1) ? argv[1] : "data/blobby.off";
    std::cout << ".off loaded" << std::endl;
    std::ifstream input(filename1);
    Mesh mesh_orig;
    if (!input || !(input >> mesh_orig))
    {
        std::cerr << "First mesh is not a valid off file." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    input.close();

    // ========================================================
    Mesh mesh_copy;
    CGAL::copy_face_graph(mesh_orig, mesh_copy);
    
    // ========================================================

    std::ofstream mesh_cpy("CPY_ANYLYZE/mesh_copy.off");
    mesh_cpy << mesh_copy;
    mesh_cpy.close();


    return 0;
}
```

Dose anyone knows how to get a complete same mesh from the original mesh? Do I need add the named parameters, or maybe using another function?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Except if you intend to write some code working with different data structures, you can use the copy constructor from the `Surface_mesh` class, `Mesh mesh_copy(mesh_orig)`. `copy_face_graph` does not do a raw copy because it works also if the input and output are of different types. However the output should be the same up to the order of the simplices.